# C++: Two dynamic arrays causes memory allocation error

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    int length = 10;
    int* H = new int(length);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
         H[i] = 0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        cout << i << ": " << "\t" << H[i] << "\n";

    double* dos = new double(length);
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        dos[i] = 1.0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
         cout << i << ": " << dos[i] << "\t" << H[i] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to create an array of doubles that all equal 1.0 and an array of ints that all equal 0. When I run this code it correctly outputs the dos array, but then I get this error

> lattice3d: malloc.c:2451: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

If I try to initialize the two arrays at the same time, I don't get a memory error, but the arrays end up with weird values within them (ex: the H array looks like [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1247506] or something to that effect). Moving where I set all the values of H and dos, changes which values are incorrect.

Comment: You need to use `[]` not `()` to allocate an array.

Comment: And of course, while you're at it, might as well use `vector<double>` instead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allocating an `int` not an array:

```
int* H = new int(length);
```

should be:

```
int* H = new int[length];
```

same with your `double` case:

```
double* dos = new double(length);
```

should be:

```
double* dos = new double[length];
```

what you are doing if it were allocated on the stack is `int H(10);` which is like `int H = 10;`, and the same for your double case; `double dos(10)` is like `double dos = 10`.

You also are leaking the arrays/values you are creating, and need to call `delete[]` at the end of your program (note this would be after you do the corrections above):

```
delete[] H;
delete[] dos;
```

Since this is tagged C++ and you are using `new`, it would be worth noting that in modern C++ that is usually best to avoid using `new` when possible.  Here, it would be better to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) than a dynamically allocated array.  There is pretty much always a better option to use than `new` that usually involves using something from the standard library.

Comment: Probably adding the need to use `delete[]` afterwards to avoid leaks later on.

Comment: Operator `new` (as well as the language under which the question itself is tagged) implies C++. C++ implies using vectors (in this case `vector<double>`) over dynamically allocated arrays. Perhaps you should consider adding this recommendation to the answer...